# Errror al parsear ej json obtenido al consumir servicios web "com.android.volley.ParseError:"

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Al consumir servicios web recibi un json y este me esta generando un error de parse

```
Error en la peticion: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":1,"name":"Test","description":"some description","price":3.1416,"finish":"some finish","color":"some great color","suitability":"where tu use it","status":true,"picture":null}
```

Este es el codigo:

```
 /****** This activity is used for show Tiles ******/
public class CatalogActivity extends Activity {

    /******* Variable It is used. to indicate how many fields are shown  ******/
    private GridLayoutManager mLayout;
    private static TileAdapter mTileAdapter;


    /****** Context to use the Strings ******/
    private static Context mContext;

    /****** Instances of gson, bus, realm, requestque, It is used to connect with web service ******/
    private static Gson mGson;
    private static RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static Bus mBus;
    private static Realm mRealm;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        mGson = new Gson();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        mBus = new Bus();

        RecyclerView MyRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_tile);
        mLayout = new GridLayoutManager(CatalogActivity.this,4);
        MyRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayout);
        MyRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        loadTiles();
        List<TileModel> realmResults = CatalogActivity
                .getRealm()
                .where(TileModel.class)
                .findAll();
        mTileAdapter = new TileAdapter(realmResults, CatalogActivity.this);
        MyRecyclerView.setAdapter(mTileAdapter);

    }

    /****** Helpers to connect with web service ******/
    public static Gson getGson() {
        return mGson;
    }

    public static RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public static Bus getBus() {
        return mBus;
    }

    public static Realm getRealm() {
        return mRealm;
    }

    /****** This methos is used for load Tiles ******/
    public static void loadTiles() {

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                JSONKeys.KEY_URL_ALL_TILES, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e("Response", response.toString());
                try {
                    JSONArray mJsonArray = response.getJSONArray(JSONKeys.KEY_NAME);
                    for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        TileModel mTileModel = CatalogActivity.getGson()
                                .fromJson(mJsonObject.toString(),
                                TileModel.class);
                        CatalogActivity.getRealm().beginTransaction();
                        CatalogActivity.getRealm().copyToRealmOrUpdate(mTileModel);
                        CatalogActivity.getRealm().commitTransaction();
                        Log.e("Agregando Pisos", mTileModel.getName());
                    }
                    CatalogActivity.getBus().post(new SuccessLoadTilesEvent(mContext
                            .getString(R.string.message_aggregate_tiles)));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error al parcear", e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Error en la peticion", error.toString());
            }
        });
        CatalogActivity.getRequestQueue().add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Android studio?

Comment: Si el servicio REST devuelve algo como esto `[{...}]`  estás recibiendo un `JSONArray` **no**   un `JSONObject`, que sería algo como esto: `{...}`  la diferencia son los corchetes. Y la forma de parsearlo es diferente. ¿Puedes confirmar lo que devuelve el servicio REST y si está bien formado?

Comment: Si me regresa un
 [ {
"id": 1,
"name": "Test",
"description": "some description",
"price": 3.1416,
"finish": "some finish",
"color": "some great color",
"suitability": "where tu use it",
"status": true,
"picture": null
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Test",
"description": "some description",
"price": 3.1416,
"finish": "some finish",
"color": "some great color",
"suitability": "where tu use it",
"status": true,
"picture": null
} ],  [ ... ] como podria parcearlo?

Comment: No se si aporte, pero mi back es rails y mi front es react y si me pasa un Array con corchetes.

Comment: podrías agregar a tu pregunta exactamente cual es la respuesta completa de tu .json. además agrega por favor tu mensaje de error completo desplegado en el LogCat

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en el resultado de la petición, tratas de realizar un parsing a una estructura json incorrecta para ser un `JsonArray`, para que sea correcta debería tener un `]` al final :

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "some description",
    "price": 3.1416,
    "finish": "some finish",
    "color": "some great color",
    "suitability": "where tu use it",
    "status": true,
    "picture": null
}]
```

si esto es así entonces solo realiza la conversión a `JSONArray` correctamente

```
   ...
   ...
   @Override
   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
     Log.e("Response", response.toString());
     try {
      // *** incorrecto porque no tienes definido un id para el array.
      // JSONArray mJsonArray = response.getJSONArray(JSONKeys.KEY_NAME);

         JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
      ...
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Como has dicho estás recibiendo un JSONArray.

Entonces el onResponse debería estar así:

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonarray) {
....
```

Luego, la forma de parsearlo sería esta:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
    String description = jsonobject.getString("description");
    ...
}
```

> Nota: Si estás usando GSON, la forma de parsearlo podría ser diferente, la utilidad de esta librería es recuperar tus respuestas y ligarlos a `Clases` que representan el objeto completo de la respuesta.